# How to detect removed element with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i need help with my code , im creating very simple game (zombie kill) and i want to detect if element was removed , is this possible with jquery ? this is part of code where i need to detect if element is removed:

```
plansza.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('zombie')) {
        e.target.live--;
        //console.log(e.target.remove())
        if (e.target.live <= 0) {
            score += 10;
            e.target.remove();
            document.querySelector('.score span').innerText = score;
        }
        if (e.target.live > 0 && e.target.remove()) {
            console.log('uciekłem')
            score -= 10;
            e.target.remove();
            document.querySelector('.score span').innerText = score;
        }

    }
```

First if delete element after 2 hits but when zombie dont get hit and go away from screen then score must be -10.

Comment: Why don't you just do something in the code that does the deletion?

Comment: You can use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: Just check if it's null, that's one way of knowing it's removed from the DOM

Comment: `e.target.remove()` doesn't return a value, why are you testing it with `if()`?

Comment: @Barmar because the OP likely thought it does return whether or not the Element has been removed

Comment: becasue i need check 2 condition: 1. if he's lives are bigger then 0 and second if its removed if both condition are correct , then score -= 10

Answer (score 0):

`remove()` always removes the element, it doesn't return a value. So you shouldn't test it with `if()`. Just call `remove()` and assume it did its job.

```
plansza.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('zombie')) {
        e.target.live--;
        if (e.target.live <= 0) {
            score += 10;
            e.target.remove();
        } else {
            console.log('uciekłem');
            score -= 10;
        }
        document.querySelector('.score span').innerText = score;
    }
});
```

Comment: I already try else , but the problem is that they have 2 lives so if you hit it 1 time , they still have 1 life so else gonna perform

Comment: So you only want to remove when `live <= 0`? Your code was removing in `if (e.target.live > 0 && e.target.remove())`

Comment: They remove when you hit it 2 times or when they go out from screen , i think maybe about they position , if position is < x then  - = 10

Comment: I updated the answer. I only remove it when `live <= 0`.

Comment: Detecting when it goes out of the screen needs to be done in other code, it's not related to clicking.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. When I click twice on each zombie it disappears.

Comment: yes the problem is with score , when you dont hit the zombie and it goes on left and removed the score should be -10 for every missed zombie

Comment: That should be done in the code that moves the zombie and detects that it has gone out the left.

Comment: and now everything is perfect :) just added it here:

zombie.addEventListener('animationend', function(e) {
            if (e.animationName === 'zombieWalk') {
                console.log(this)
                score -= 10;
                this.remove();
                document.querySelector('.score span').innerText = score;
            }
        });     Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found it easiest to just bind a DOMSubtreeModified event to the parent element.

```
$(yourParentElement).bind("DOMSubtreeModified", DOMChanged);

function DOMChanged(){
   alert('child element removed');
}
```